# QGIS Web Client: Where to upload my .shp files?

Tags: qgis-web-client, file-path

I've installed QGIS Server and QGIS Web Client on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server according to these instructions:
https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client

When I load my own project with the Web Client, it shows the correct table of contents but no map, just the box that says "loading map". 
A WMS service of my project is running fine and the two sample projects (helloworld, naturalearth) are displayed by the Web Client as well. Looks like the client doesn't find the data for the project.

On the server my folder structure looks like this:

/qgis-web-client/projects/myprojectfile.qgs

/qgis-web-client/projects/shapefiles/myfirstlayer.shp

/qgis-web-client/projects/shapefiles/mysecondlayer.shp

/qgis-web-client/projects/shapefiles/...

The project was created with QGIS 1.8 for Windows using relative paths and this folder structure:

/myproject/myprojectfile.qgs

/myproject/shapefiles/myfirstlayer.shp ...

Where do I have to put the "shapefiles" folder? Do I need to specify that location somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris! I tried to put my files in /qgis-web-client/data/myproject/shapefiles/ and /qgis-web-client/data/shapefiles/, both chmodded to 664. Unfortunately its still stuck while loading :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that this is not an answer. Please put this text in a comment with the `Add Comment` below Chris' answer.

Comment: do you have all the shapefile files, not just the .shp file?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to put my shapefiles, into /qgis-web-client/data/ and into /tmp/

Both work fine, because the location path is mentioned into the QGIS project I guess.

But in order to see them into the QGIS-Web-Client, Apache (www-data) needs to have the right to open them. Which means, the 'other' needs to be able to read your shapefiles: rw-rw-**r**--

Hope that helps

Chris

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris! I tried to put my files in /qgis-web-client/data/myproject/shapefiles/ and /qgis-web-client/data/shapefiles/, both chmodded to 664. Unfortunately its still stuck while loading :( Any other ideas?